# How to format logs in fluend while also adding additional fileds?

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I'd want to add additioanl fields to a json log, such as timestamp and metadata, while also keeping the log itself as a string value of a "message" key.

For example, if the log I'm receiving is `{"Hello":"World"}`, what I eventually want is to have the following:

```
{
 "timestamp":"2020-01-101T01:02:03",
 "metadata":{"foo":"bar"},
 "message": "{\"Hello\":\"World\"}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [filter_record_transformer](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer).

Something like:

```
<filter foo.bar>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    metadata '{"foo":"bar"}'
    timestamp ${time.iso8601}
  </record>
</filter>
```

**Note:** `enable_ruby true` is required to transform `${time}` to the format you're after. If you don't need to manipulate strings or similar, you can leave that line out.